# Bounds on the root at which a rising factorial is equal to $1$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math

An old Olympiad problem I found deals with the roots of this fascinating polynomial:

$$P(x) = x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+2020) - 1$$

The problem asked me to prove that there is only one positive root $x_0$ (follows easily through monotonicity and/or through derivatives), but also asks to prove the following bound for $x_0$:

$$\frac{1}{2020!+10}<x_0<\frac{1}{2020!+6}$$
This is where I was stuck. That $x_0$ is close to $\frac{1}{2020! }$ is fairly clear, especially if one expands the polynomial. How can I obtain the exact bounds required on $x_0$?

Comment: Given a polynomial $P(x) = a_n x^n + \ldots + a_1 x +a_0$, McLaurin boundaries for polynomial roots states that for every root $\xi$ $$ \frac{1}{1 + \mu}< |\xi| < 1 + \lambda $$ where $\lambda = \displaystyle \max_{0 \leq k < n} |\displaystyle\frac{a_k}{a_n}| $ and
$\mu = \displaystyle \max_{0 < k \leq n} |\displaystyle\frac{a_k}{a_0}|$

Comment: @IkerUCM do not see how either of these inequalities help. Note that $a_n = 1$ and thus the RHS is $1 + 2020!$, which is hardly a useful bound.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Have you considered upvoting and accepting my answer? Please comment if my answer can be improved. (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: $x-\frac{x^2}2\le\ln(1+x)\le x$ if $0\le x\le1$.
Proof: When $x=0$, we get equalities. Verify that $\frac{d(x-\frac{x^2}2)}{dx}\le\frac{d(\ln(1+x))}{dx}\le\frac{dx}{dx}$ when $0\le x\le1$.

---

**Claim**: $6+\frac1{12}< \sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac1i < 10$.
Proof. There are two approaches.

- We can use a pocket calculator. 
  $$7.61\approx\ln(2021)<\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac1i<1+\ln(2020)\approx8.61$$
- We do not have a pocket calculator.

  - $1+1/2+1/3+1/4=2+\frac{1}{12}.$
    $\sum_{i=5}^{1024}\frac1i=(\frac15+\cdots+\frac18) + (\frac19+\cdots+\frac1{16}) +\cdots + (\frac1{513}+\cdots+\frac1{1024}) \\
    > \frac48+\frac8{16}+\cdots+\frac{512}{1024}=\frac12 \cdot 8 = 4.$
    $\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac1i>1+1/2+1/3+1/4+\sum_{i=5}^{1024}\frac1i>6+\frac1{12}.$
  - $\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\le(1+\frac12+\frac13)+(\frac1{4}+\frac1{5}) +(\frac1{6}+\frac17 +\frac1{8}) +(\frac1{8}+\cdots +\frac1{11}) +(\frac1{12}+\cdots +\frac1{17}) +(\frac1{18}+\cdots +\frac1{26}) +(\frac1{26}+\cdots +\frac1{38}) +(\frac1{38}+\cdots +\frac1{56}) +(\frac1{56}+\cdots +\frac1{83}) +(\frac1{84}+\cdots +\frac1{125}) +(\frac1{126}+\cdots +\frac1{188}) +(\frac1{188}+\cdots +\frac1{281}) +(\frac1{282}+\cdots +\frac1{422}) +(\frac1{422}+\cdots +\frac1{632}) +(\frac1{632}+\cdots +\frac1{947}) +(\frac1{948}+\cdots +\frac1{1421}) +(\frac1{1422}+\cdots +\frac1{2132})\\<2+\frac{2}{4} +\frac{3}{6} +\frac{4}{8} +\frac{6}{12} +\frac{9}{18} +\frac{13}{26} +\frac{19}{38} +\frac{28}{56} +\frac{42}{84} +\frac{63}{126} +\frac{94}{188} +\frac{141}{282} +\frac{211}{422} +\frac{316}{632} +\frac{474}{948} +\frac{711}{1422}\\=2+\frac12\cdot16=10$

---

$$\begin{aligned}&\qquad\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\ln(1+\frac1{i(2020!+10)})\\
&\le\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac1{i(2020!+10)}=\frac1{2020!+10}\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac1i\\
&< \frac{10}{2020!+10}< \frac{10}{2020!}-\frac{(\frac{10}{2020!})^2}2\\
&\le\ln(1+\frac{10}{2020!})
\end{aligned}$$
which means $P(\frac1{2020!+10}) < 0$.

$$\begin{aligned}&\qquad\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\ln(1+\frac1{i(2020!+6)})\\
&\ge\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\left(\frac1{i(2020!+6)}-\frac{\left(\frac1{i(2020!+6)}\right)^2}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2020!+6}\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac1i-\frac1{(2020!+6)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{2020}\frac1{i^2}\\
&\ge \frac{6+\frac1{12}}{2020!+6}-\frac{2020}{(2020!+6)^2}> \frac6{2020!}\\
&\ge \ln(1+\frac6{2020!})
\end{aligned}$$
which means $P(\frac1{2020!+6}) > 0$.

Hence, $$\frac{1}{2020!+10}<x_0<\frac{1}{2020!+6}.$$

Comment: $x_0\approx\frac1{2020!+8.188316}$

Comment: $r_i\approx\frac1{i!+\sum_{j=1}^i\frac1j}$, where $r_i$ is the positive root of $P_i(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+i)-1$.